# common controls in winforms like master page in asp.net

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a windows (winforms) application, but I stuck at some things.
In asp.net there is a "master page" in web sites, so using this master page we can place a common controls in master page and later it will be used in all other pages. We dont need to place those controls on every page which are already placed on master page.
In winforms I want to do same thing like I want to place a menubar as common control on all forms. I dont want to place this menu bar manually on all other form because it will be time consuming and there is a chance to make a mistake.
But how to do this in winforms?
thanks guys.

Comment: Project > Add New Item > Windows Form node, pick "Inherited Form".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inherit another form on your user forms as a template.

Create your template form first...

Then add the inherit to your user forms.

```
Public Class User_From1
    Inherits My_Template_Form

End Class
```

Comment: it works in way what I want to. but I cant change controls size like I change in other forms. I have to change it manually, go to in control properties and then change the size, it allows only drag and drop. but thanks to all of you sir.

Comment: Ya it gets complicated if you want a lot of dynamic stuff.

Comment: It's kind of iffy for more than the simple stuff.